# Crash running on device when Run (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app I am running on a device.

When I Build and Run, the **Build is successful**, but when it **Runs I get a crash**.

[image]

I'm not sure what information it is telling me exactly. I can't figure out where to even start to debug this?

Comment: Using [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/awsdk)?

Comment: @meaning-matters whoa, yes! Is that the cause of this? I'm reading thru but not seeing it yet. (But thats amazing you knew that was probably it!)

Comment: The console gives you path to file and line where the error occured and you don't know whatline 60 is it referring to?

Comment: @DominikBucher its a private repo and I believe it is pointing to something on their CI server

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a exception breakpoint. See more details [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/how-to-create-exception-breakpoints-in-xcode) how to add an exception breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

1.Check All Your IBOutlets If they are connected properly. (In your    viewcontroller)

2.Clean Your Derived Data (Clean & Run )
3.Check If you are Unwrapping Forcefully using (!) and its returning nil . Make Things optional By using (?)
4.If above Steps Wont Work Add exception breakpoint And Post the line at which it crash

.